# App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core.git

Tags: heroku, ytdl

Im trying to make a discord.js bot and i got to implementing music playing into it. But since i have it hosted on Heroku i needed to install the https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core.git
buildpack but i get this error:

```
Build succeeded!
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/fent/node-ytdl-core.git
       bash: /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/11443dd76ad0133018597f04ce3b59d71d136830/bin/detect: No such file or directory
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

Any possible solutions?

Comment: I'd suggest reading the `More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure` URL but it talks about what to do when the detection script hates your build, and in this case, the detection script seems to be missing entirely instead. Git isn't involved here though: it's just the messenger, delivering your commits to Heroku.

Comment: Update: I resolved the issue: I did this command on my computer: npm install @discordjs/opus ffmpeg-static yt-search ytdl-core
I also deleted the buildpack. This resolved all the issues and not ytdl-core works perfectly.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer as comments can disappear without warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I resolved the issue: I did this command on my computer: npm install @discordjs/opus ffmpeg-static yt-search ytdl-core I also deleted the buildpack. This resolved all the issues and now ytdl-core works perfectly.